# Div Overflow and scroll left

Tags: html, css

I've got a div that has a fixed height of 500px. Contained in the div is images. I've got them stacking and overflowing the way I like currently but instead of when the visible div becomes full filling to the bottom and scrolling down, how do I force the div to scroll on the x axis. Here is my current HTML and SCSS

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="img/samples/sample-photo-1.jpg" class="wedding" />
    <img src="img/samples/sample-photo-2.jpg" class="portraights" />
    <img src="img/samples/sample-photo-2.jpg" class="family" />
    <img src="img/samples/sample-photo-1.jpg" class="wedding" />
    <img src="img/samples/sample-photo-1.jpg" class="wedding" />
    <img src="img/samples/sample-photo-2.jpg" class="portraights" />
    <img src="img/samples/sample-photo-2.jpg" class="family" />
    <img src="img/samples/sample-photo-2.jpg" class="portraights" />
    <img src="img/samples/sample-photo-2.jpg" class="family" />
</div>

.gallery {
      clear: both;
      margin: 0 0 0 15px;
      max-height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      display: block;
      img { 
        float: left;
        padding: 3px;
      }
}
```

Comment: So the images are vertically stacked, and scrolling on the y-axis, but you want them left aligned, floated horizontally, and to scroll on the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: Made a mistake not using scss in fiddle, which revealed how `float:left` ripped your images from the text flow.

```
.gallery {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    img { 
        padding: 3px;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RgWy6/)

Answer (score -1):

```
.gallery {
      clear: both;
      margin: 0 0 0 15px;
      max-height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      display: block;
}

img { 
      float: left;
      padding: 3px;
}
```

Try this please

or this:

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Comment: [SCSS, look it up!](http://sass-lang.com/) And setting overflow-x to auto does nothing (except hiding the scroll bars automatically when there is no overflow.)

Comment: Sorry. It's nothing personal. I downvoted your answer because you didn't test it beforehand and it doesn't work. And I don't know if you don't know SCSS or didn't read the question. Don't blurt out stuff if you don't know. It is unhelpful. - Also, I'm not OP (Anyone can downvote you).